# Cloud Foundry docker image deployment & blue-green deployment

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

Is Cloud Foundry [blue-green deployment](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html) and especially [cf-blue-green-deploy plugin](https://github.com/bluemixgaragelondon/cf-blue-green-deploy) compatible with [docker image deployment](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/push-docker.html)?